# Where is user 'nginx' in nginx on debian 8

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I had nginx `1.6.0` on Debian 7 (wheezy), and now I want to install nginx on Debian 8 (Jessie). The version of this new nginx is `1.6.2`. I copied the old version of the configuration file `nginx.conf` to the new server, but when I try to start the service, It fails:

```
service nginx restart
```

output:

```
nginx nginx[10743]: nginx: [emerg] getpwnam("nginx") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
```

I know my problem is the first line in `nginx.conf`:

```
user    nginx;
```

And I know too, if I changed this line to `user   www-data`, the problem will disappear, but why is that so? I have also used nginx as a load balancer not as a webserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ man getpwnam
```

> The getpwnam() function returns a pointer to a structure containing the
>          broken-out  fields  of  the  record in the password database (e.g., the
>          local password file /etc/passwd, NIS, and LDAP) that matches the  user‐
>          name name.

The user `nginx` does not exist. You can create it or you can just use `www-data` as the user.

Comment: Yes, you right. In this new version of `nginx`, the configuration file `default` has went to the directory `sites-available`, but my old configuration file was in the directory `conf.d`. In fact my problem was that, but I didn't understand and I guessed the problem is no user `nginx` in the new version. Regardless of these notes, I thank you for your guidance.